# How to interpret Gelman's multivariate Gaussian prior for multinomial distribution?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, hierarchical-bayesian, softmax

Andrew Gelman suggested the use of a multivariate Normal distribution as prior for hierarchical models that have a multinomial distribution at the lowest level (http://andrewgelman.com/2009/04/29/conjugate_prior/). I find that this model works well, and I can interpret the means for the multivariate Normal by converting them to probabilities using a "softmax" transform. However, the raw values for the means don't really mean anything in terms of the problem's context, and histograms of the softmaxed Monte Carlo draws assume a bimodal distribution which is hard to make sense of.

Is there a transform that can preserve the distribution of the Monte Carlo draws while converting the unrestricted means for the Normal prior so they can be interpreted as a probability vector summing to 1?